# Get the email address of the current user in Outlook 2007

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, outlook-addin, office-2007

I have an Outlook add in written in C#.

I was wondering how or if I could get the email address of the current user?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Namespace.CurrentUser`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220041(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thats VBA though, not C#. I cant seem to find that in C#

Comment: you could try `myEmailAddress = this.ActiveExplorer().Session.CurrentUser.EmailAddress;` or try other solutions here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/d2d9bf23-e27f-4f30-9199-42833d6919a4/

Answer (score 14):

Tested in VS 2010, .NET 4.0, Outlook 2010:

```
var emailAddress = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress;
```

Comment: Why not shorten it to var emailAddress = this.Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address? You also need to check that AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser is valid - for a user with no Exchange in the profile, GetExchangeUser will return null.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, I deliberately wrote it in long-form so that it would be obvious where it comes from. At the same time, I deliberately answered it with the minimum number of lines of code.  I leave it to the OP to write defensive code in the context of his/her application.

Comment: I think you are missing the point - `ActiveExplorer()` is not necessary and can return null. Get rid of it - use `this.Application.Session.CurrentUser.Address`

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the definition of "the current user address".

1. The address of the primary account in Outlook can be retrieved from `Appication.Session.CurrentUser` (returns `Recipient` object). Use `Recipient.Address` property. Note however that for an Exchange account (`Recipient.AddressEntry.Type == "EX"`) you will receive an EX type address. To retrieve the SMTP address, use `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`. Be prepared to handle nulls/exceptions in case of errors.

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi), use `IMAPISession::QueryIdentity` (you can test it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) - I am its author - click IMAPISession button, then QueryIdentity). You can then read the `PR_ADDRTYPE` property ("EX" vs "SMTP") and `PR_EMAIL_ADDRESS` (when `PR_ADDRTYPE` = "SMTP") or (in case of Exchange) `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` (not guaranteed to be present) and `PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES` (multivalued property with Exchange addresses, including all proxy (alias) addresses, EX and SMTP).

2. In case of multiple accounts in the profile, an email can be sent or received through multiple accounts. In that case use `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` (returns `Account` object, can be null - in that case use `Application.Session.CurentUser`). This is valid both for received, sent or emails being composed (`Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem` or `Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse`).
3. All accounts in a given profile can be accessed using the `Namespace.Accounts` collection `(Application.Session.Accounts`). Account's address can be accessed using `Account.SmtpAddress` property.
   Note that the Outlook Object Model only exposes mail accounts. Some store accounts (such as PST) are not in the collection since they do not have an intrinsic user identity even if some other accounts (such as POP3/SMTP) can deliver to that store. If you want to access all accounts, you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) and its [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`Accounts` collection ([RDOAccounts](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm) object).

On the Extended MAPI level, the accounts are exposed through the [IOlkAccountManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff960327.aspx) interface. You can play with it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) if you click the IOlkAccountManager button.

4. In case of delegate Exchange stores, the store owner is not exposed through the Outlook Object Model. You can either use Extended MAPI (note that the `PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID` property is only exposed by the online store, it is not available in a cached store). You can parse the Exchange store entry id and extract the EX type address from it. You can then construct the GAL object entry id given the EX address. You can also access the store owner using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [RDOExchangeMailboxStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOExchangeMailboxStore) object and its `Owner` property.

Comment: In case if an appointment is being created in the calendar, is there a way to use OOM to learn which email account will be associated with it? I.e. to map the calendar to the account when we have multiple accounts in the profile.

Comment: Not in Sure, read the appointment Parent property, cast it to the Folder object, read the Folder.Store property. Loop through the Namespace.Accounts collection and compare the value of the Account.DeliveryStore.EntryID property with the entry id of the appointment's parent store entry id.

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime, I found that AppointmentItem just created already contains one Recipient in its Recipients collection and this recipient has the email I need (so that the organizer is already initialized). Looks like an easier method (for this particular task). Or are there any drawbacks of this approach? It's provided that appointments in question are created by my own code so I don't have to deal with the case when the appointment has already existed and its recipients list could be non-default and cannot be relied on.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the normal POP/IMAP server, you get the e-mail address with:
Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address;

With Exchange Server, you get the e-mail address with:
Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress;

Answer (score 0):

Try `outlookObject.ActiveExplorer().Session.CurrentUser.Address`. Worked for me on VS10, Outlook 2007, .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Anyone passing by, I'd strongly advice using `Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address`
instead of anything using 
`Application.ActiveExplorer().Session`,
 as `ActiveExplorer()` might return a `NullReferenceException`, for instance when opening an email via Outlook.