# Is there a way to programmatically fetch your email address for an Outlook addin?

Tags: vb.net, com-interop, outlook-addin

as the title says, I'd like to be able to get my own or whoever's email address the user of the add in may be, and store in in a string variable.

Comment: Found the answer I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761521/get-the-email-address-of-the-current-user-in-outlook-2007

Comment: Found what I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761521/get-the-email-address-of-the-current-user-in-outlook-2007

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hirendra_singh/accessing-outlook-contacts-list-in-C-Sharp/

Its in c#, but should be able to help you nevertheless!