# How to use Application dialogs in c#?

Tags: c#, dialog

Im trying to follow this Microsoft tutorial to display the names of a distribution list in c#

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-get-members-of-an-exchange-distribution-list

`This example prompts the user to select an Exchange distribution list from the Select Names dialog box and expands the distribution list to display its members.`

except when I get an error here

[image]

I have this in a console app project. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by creating an Application instance, as per suggestion made by the prompt in your screenshot. Like so:

```
Application app = new Application();
Outlook.SelectNamesDialog snd = app.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog();
```

#### Sources:

1. [How to invoke a method with (Outlook.Application application) as parameter in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334242/how-to-invoke-a-method-with-outlook-application-application-as-parameter-in-c)