# Excel VBA get (unique) ID of excel-user

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently looking for a way to identity a user of a workbook - preferably by hooking into some account information from Microsoft Excel. I've found the following line which gets the Excel username:

`Application.UserName`

However this isn't quite "safe" (unique) Enough as I Wish to make sure that only One person/user can use the workbook. It's Easy just Change the username in excel.

Is it possible to get some other account information? I'd prefer the e-mail used with the office/Excel account, however some other answers Say that it probably isn't possible to get that value(??).

Answer (score 0):

By "safe" you mean unique? Try

```
Environ("username")
```

Application Username is the name of the User set in Excel Tools>Options

Environ("username") is the user name which you log into Windows with.

Comment: It's a good suggestion, however I might not be able to have the users state their Windows username. Do you know whether the returned username is the e-mail, such as in Windows 10 when I (personally) log in with my e-mail?

Comment: I get my nt login when I call 
myName = Environ("username")

Answer (score 0):

I had spent some time locating how to send an e-mail to the sending account (for self-notifications), and found an answer, and experimented, and explored some more, until I found that the following worked for my purposes:

```
Outlook.Application.Session.CurrentUser.Address
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28459162/9259306) recommends `Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address`

However, if you are using early-binding in your code, you'll need to add a reference to the `Microsoft Outlook [version#] Object Library`.

---

**Also**, note that the above does not return a value which can be compared with either a hard-coded or an in-put value in standard email format, i.e. "myname@account.com".

---

**However**, for the way my Outlook is setup, I can access my e-mail address as a string via:

```
outlookApp.Session.Accounts(1).DisplayName
```

I will caution, however, that I have also read of times when this gave an unexpected value. It is also based of the **first** account listed; which may not always be the account for the `CurrentUser`, depending (on ?).

Comment: Won't this technique also require that the user actually has outlook installed and an e-mail account logged in/attached?

Comment: Yes, it would. I assumed that was the cause, but after rereading your question, I realize it's not....

Comment: @Chri.s Experimenting around, the following returned my email address, but I haven't had a chance to test in a different situation; and it is entirely possible that this just _happened_ to return the right result. `Environ("Username") & "@" & Replace(LCase(Environ("Userdnsdomain")), "corp.", "")`

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work on my computer and only returned `username@` without the domain.